# Cross-browser input text focus system?

Tags: javascript, html, focus

I have the following code, where `soundid` is an integer between (not including) 0 and 11, and all the element names exist. Currently, it does not focus in many browsers. What should I add, modify or change it into to make it able to focus into an `input type="text"` element?

Code:

```
document.getElementById("fo" + soundid + "cus").click();
document.getElementById("fo1cus").click();
$("#spellingf" + soundid).select();
$("#spellingf" + soundid).focus();
document.getElementById("spellingf" + soundid).focus();
$("#fo" + soundid + "cus").click();
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you mean?

Comment: Google Chrome (Mac) and Safari (Windows). They are both close to the most updated version, or are the updated version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native HTML Elements don't have an `click` method. So this:

```
document.getElementById("fo" + soundid + "cus").click();
```

and this:

```
document.getElementById("fo1cus").click();
```

will throw an error. The error will stop the code execution s the rest of the code won't be executed. That's why it doesn't work. So use this code:

```
$("#fo" + soundid + "cus").click();
$("#fo1cus").click();
$("#spellingf" + soundid).focus();
$("#fo" + soundid + "cus").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're asking here tbh.

Giving your input and id attribute and selecting on that id will work cross browser.

```
$('#fo1cus').focus(function() {
  alert('Handler for .focus() called.');
});
```

Comment: sorry, I mean for it to click / focus / select the text box.